# What is the type of traceback objects in Python?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

```
import sys

try:
    raise Exception('foobar')
except:
    info = sys.exc_info()

print(type(e[2])) # <class 'traceback'>
help(traceback) # NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined
```

What exactly is the type of the traceback objects that Python uses for exception reporting?

The docs on [sys.exc_info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) mention the Reference Manual, but while I've found plenty of information on how to manipulate traceback instances, I want to be able to access the type (class) itself.

Comment: Just because there is a class wiht the `__name__ == 'traceback'` doesn't mean that in the global namespace, `traceback` refers to that class.

Comment: What are you even planning to do with this type? Having access to the type object doesn't get you much.

Comment: You're already accessing the type with `type(e[2])`, by the way.

Comment: Type annotations and curiosity.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`traceback` object is an instance of [`TracebackType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.TracebackType) present under types module.

> `types.TracebackType`
>
> The type of `traceback` objects such as found in `sys.exc_info()[2]`.

```
>>> from types import TracebackType    
>>> isinstance(info[2], TracebackType)
True    
>>> TracebackType
<class 'traceback'>
```

---

As [pointed out by @user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337853/what-is-the-type-of-traceback-objects-in-python/45337916#comment77637991_45337916) the name `TracebackType` is basically an alias to the internal `traceback` type and is [set by raising an exception](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/traceback.c#L189) in types module. The actual [`traceback` type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/traceback.c#L75) can be found in CPython code.

Comment: It should be noted that this isn't the "true" name of the type - there's no "true" name - and it's not the place where the type is defined. `types.py` just raises an exception to get the traceback and sets `TracebackType = type(tb)`.

Comment: @user2357112 Updated.